# componentdidmount - prop-types validation

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Thank you for your time.

Noob React question... i know componentDidMount will fire after the first render of the component, which is why the `prop-types` eslint error i am getting is being triggered. However i am not sure how you would fix this and add validation, propTypes validation fires before the `getArticles()` function therefore if i declare a propTypes it returns undefined... as i.e. articles has not been defined until after the first render and and componentDidMount is called... have had a good dig and cant see a simple solution for what i assume is a common problem??

Question - how do you validate props that have not yet been fetched.

```
class ArticlesList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getArticles();
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.articles.map(({ id, date, heading, body }) => (
      <Article key={id} date={date} heading={heading} body={body} />
    ));
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { articles: state.articles };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getArticles })(ArticlesList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructure the componentDidMount i.e.

```
componentDidMount() {
{ getArticles } = this.props;
getArticles();
}
```

and adding

```
ArticlesList.propTypes = {
  getArticles: PropTypes.func,
  articles: PropTypes.array,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you would only get an issue for an undefined prop if you had add to your prop validation `isRequired` like `PropTypes.array.isRequired`. With that in mind you only need to define correctly your propType:

```
ArticlesList.propTypes = {
  articles: PropTypes.array,
}
```

Comment: Thanks - yes i had added that, have found the solution was to destructure the componentDidMount i.e. componentDidMount has const { getArticles } = this.props; and getArticles(); within it, which seems to resolve the eslint error.